# Creating a recursive function for getting data from a paginated API with Fetch API on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to learn a little bit about React and the idea here was to get data recursively from a REST API e store in one variable. I tried to store with setState and also with a global variable, but insite of the function i've got results and exaclty what I wat, but outside, nothing. Can't understant what i'm doing wrong in this case.

````
export default function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  let completeData = [];

  function getData (url) {
    if(url != null) {
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then( result => {
          completeData = [...completeData, ...result.results];

          //here the data are in variable
          console.log(completeData)
          getData(result.info.next);
        });
    }
  }

  getData(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=0`);

  //here they're not
  console.log('--------');
  console.log(completeData);
  
  return (
    <div className="app">

    </div>
  )
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to handle a side effect like fetching data, you can use ***useEffect*** hooks

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const App = ({posts}) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(()=> {
    fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=0')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data.results))
  }, []);
  
  if (data === null) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}
    </div>
      );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for that! Previously I was doing the exact same thing, but the console.log dosn't printed that at all. I think my mistake was to use that instead of a debbug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setData` when you append it, e.g. `setData(completeData);`

```
export default function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  function getData (url) {
    if(url != null) {
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then( result => {
          // Use your state data value here and the result...
          const completeData = [...data, ...result.results];
           
          // Set the state value here...
          setData(completeData);

          getData(result.info.next);
        });
    }
  }

  getData(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=0`);
  
  return (
    <div className="app">
      {data.map((character) => (
        <div>{JSON.stringify(character)}</div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Refer to the useState documentation for more details: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html